# adf.ly API without any adverts

Tags: php, api

I want to short URLs without any ads, then I plan to change links later to banner or int
but i use this API:

> `http://api.adf.ly/api.php?key=c02fe2b360ee4b566a4f1e14d84b279b&uid=3141484&advert_type=banner&domain=adf.ly&url=http://somewebsite.com`

If I remove `advert_type=banner` it will instead use `advert_type=int`, but I want to shorten URLs without any ads. So, I need some suggestion to create short URLs without any ads using the API, but I want to change its type later to banner or full ads.

Comment: Maybe the Google URL shortener?

Answer (score 1):

Adfly is a PPV *(Pay-Per-View)* service, if you're looking for a URL shortener without ads try a different service.

I suggest [Google url shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) and here's a good [Davidwalsh tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/google-url) implementation example.

Comment: i know it, but when we short a url we have 3 option,with full ads,with banner ads,and without any ads, in API i want to create a no ads url,and later i can change it to banner or full ads in my control pannel

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://api.adf.ly/api.php?key=[REDACTED]&uid=[REDACTED]&advert_type=int&domain=adf.ly&url=http://domain.php');

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to delete the advertisements, I'd recommended using a different URL shorten'er.  If you're planning on adding your own domain to your URL shorten'er I'd recommended hosting your own (for $2ish dollars) with [Superior Networks](http://www.superior-networks.com/) or any other host using [Yourls](http://www.Yourls.org/).

You're also able to use Bitly's own service hooking up your domain for 100% free hosting, but isn't as short.  Please read bitly's support page for how to set it up.  (I can't link to it until I get 10 reputation, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Informacion de la API de adf.ly:

```
advert_type Optional • Interstitial advertising
    ◦ advert_type=int
    ◦ advert_type=interstitial
    ◦ advert_type=1
• Framed banner
    ◦ advert_type=banner
    ◦ advert_type=3
• No advertising
    ◦ advert_type=2
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer OP's question. Give him some context on what he should do with that data to achieve what wants. A code example would be more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

advert_type=2

Comment: Can you provide some context?